# Open pdf, docx, xlsx, pptx and all images in Windows Phone app without launcher

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

In Windows Phone app project, in solution explorer I added many documents such as pdf files, doc files, Images.
I want to show all those files list on my Windows Phone app screen, and after clicking on that it will open in our app, not want to use launcher, How should I proceed?

I am successful in Viewing PDF file in the Windows Phone app using ComponentOne 3rd party reference, but I tried but can't view excel file & doc file in the windows phone app.

```
private void pdf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        var resource = Application.GetResourceStream
       (new Uri("Document;component/WORKSAPPLICATIONS_2014_India.pdf", UriKind.Relative));
        this.viewpdf.LoadDocument(resource.Stream);
}
```

& I tried for viewing Xls file by below code, but how to proceed ahead I don't know.

```
StreamResourceInfo sri = Application.GetResourceStream
(new Uri("Document;component/Resources/PRO-N-APPS Members Details.xlsx", UriKind.Relative));
var book = new C1.Phone.Excel.C1XLBook();
book.Load(sri.Stream, C1.Phone.Excel.FileFormat.OpenXml);
```

If there is any simple way without the any 3rd party controlo or simply by Webbrowser then it will be best. Please let me know the proper way, only I want that document xls sheet can't be editable.

Note: sorry for the Indentation of the code, I can't indent properly here as Stackoverflow setting not understood to me.